# Desktop WiFi stops after reboot for router but not phone

Tags: wireless

I have:

- A lovely ancient desktop running Xubuntu 22.04
- A Dell Latitude E7250 (5-year old 12.5" screen enterprise laptop) running Xubuntu 20.04
- A Lenovo P53 (3-year old larger enteprise laptop) running Xubuntu 22.04
- A Linksys AE6000 wireless adapter (`lsusb` reports `ID 13b1:003e Linksys AE6000 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [MediaTek MT7610U]`)
- A Netgear N900 dual-band wireless router
- A Pixel 5

When I reboot the desktop, it stops being able to connect to the router for about a day (or perhaps exactly 86400 seconds), after which it spontaneously heals itself and connects to the router just fine.

If I set the phone up as a hotspot, the computer connects to it just fine right out of reboot.

I can see the router just fine in the network manager pulldown and using `nmcli device wifi list`.

At this point, I reach the end of my clue-rope, and I need to declare myself clueless.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the computer was doing the same thing using Xubuntu 20.04.  I did a distribution upgrade, and I *may* have done a distribution upgrade from 18.04 -- so there may be some residual nastiness in a configuration file somewhere that's just been carried forward.

The same external symptoms happen with a Dell Latitude E7250 with Xubuntu 20.04, but they **do not happen** with a Lenovo P53.

In the case of the Dell, it works just fine off of my house router.

So somehow the problem is hardware- or installation related.

Here's a snippit from syslog, where the system is trying to connect to my wireless router at `timshop24`.  My apologies for the huge data dump, but I'm not sure what's relevant.

```
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlxc4411e38b694.IPv6 with address fe80::b70b:15f7:6694:16ac.
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Registering new address record for fe80::b70b:15f7:6694:16ac on wlxc4411e38b694.*.
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::b70b:15f7:6694:16ac on wlxc4411e38b694.
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlxc4411e38b694.IPv6 with address fe80::b70b:15f7:6694:16ac.
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Interface wlxc4411e38b694.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.97.165 on wlxc4411e38b694.
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlxc4411e38b694.IPv4 with address 192.168.97.165.
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Interface wlxc4411e38b694.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo systemd-resolved[1267]: wlxc4411e38b694: Bus client set default route setting: no
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo systemd-resolved[1267]: wlxc4411e38b694: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jul 26 09:57:48 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Jul 26 09:57:51 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: message repeated 2 times: [ wlxc4411e38b694: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending]
Jul 26 09:57:52 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jul 26 09:57:57 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Jul 26 09:57:58 Servo systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5419] device (wlxc4411e38b694): Activation: starting connection 'timshop24' (02b8accc-8883-4c46-ad85-579c5e66ae3e)
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5421] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="02b8accc-8883-4c46-ad85-579c5e66ae3e" name="timshop24" pid=3345 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5423] device (wlxc4411e38b694): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5430] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5436] device (wlxc4411e38b694): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5440] device (wlxc4411e38b694): Activation: (wifi) access point 'timshop24' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5441] device (wlxc4411e38b694): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5444] sup-iface[aeadb2a6d65ec424,0,wlxc4411e38b694]: wps: type pbc start...
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5477] device (wlxc4411e38b694): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5484] device (wlxc4411e38b694): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5489] device (wlxc4411e38b694): Activation: (wifi) connection 'timshop24' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5489] Config: added 'ssid' value 'timshop24'
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5489] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5490] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5490] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5490] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390679.5491] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jul 26 09:57:59 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: WPS-CANCEL 
Jul 26 09:58:01 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390681.5958] device (wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 26 09:58:01 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390681.5959] device (p2p-dev-wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 26 09:58:06 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e (SSID='timshop24' freq=2462 MHz)
Jul 26 09:58:06 Servo kernel: [ 4089.669891] wlxc4411e38b694: authenticate with 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.1337] device (wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.1337] device (p2p-dev-wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo kernel: [ 4090.162091] wlxc4411e38b694: send auth to 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e (try 1/3)
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: Trying to associate with 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e (SSID='timshop24' freq=2462 MHz)
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.1405] device (wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.1405] device (p2p-dev-wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo kernel: [ 4090.169771] wlxc4411e38b694: authenticated
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo kernel: [ 4090.176804] wlxc4411e38b694: associate with 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e (try 1/3)
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo kernel: [ 4090.181443] wlxc4411e38b694: RX AssocResp from 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: Associated with 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo kernel: [ 4090.197523] wlxc4411e38b694: associated
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.1735] device (wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.1735] device (p2p-dev-wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.2331] device (wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.2332] device (wlxc4411e38b694): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "timshop24"
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.2332] device (p2p-dev-wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.2334] device (wlxc4411e38b694): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390687.2340] dhcp4 (wlxc4411e38b694): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo kernel: [ 4090.260948] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlxc4411e38b694: link becomes ready
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlxc4411e38b694.IPv6 with address fe80::7bf7:9cb5:8453:53bf.
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: New relevant interface wlxc4411e38b694.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Registering new address record for fe80::7bf7:9cb5:8453:53bf on wlxc4411e38b694.*.
Jul 26 09:58:07 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-24 noise=9999 txrate=14400
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390732.7128] device (wlxc4411e38b694): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390732.7136] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <warn>  [1690390732.7142] device (wlxc4411e38b694): Activation: failed for connection 'timshop24'
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390732.7146] device (wlxc4411e38b694): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::7bf7:9cb5:8453:53bf on wlxc4411e38b694.
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlxc4411e38b694.IPv6 with address fe80::7bf7:9cb5:8453:53bf.
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo avahi-daemon[1279]: Interface wlxc4411e38b694.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390732.7469] dhcp4 (wlxc4411e38b694): canceled DHCP transaction
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo kernel: [ 4135.778156] wlxc4411e38b694: deauthenticating from 04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=04:a1:51:cc:ea:9e reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390732.9365] device (wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo NetworkManager[1282]: <info>  [1690390732.9365] device (p2p-dev-wlxc4411e38b694): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 26 09:58:52 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 26 09:58:53 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Jul 26 09:58:54 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jul 26 09:58:56 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Jul 26 09:58:57 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jul 26 09:59:17 Servo wpa_supplicant[1317]: wlxc4411e38b694: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run the command to restart Network Manager as follows?

"sudo systemctl restart network-manager"

There's some suggestions here: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/network-connection-needs-restarting-in-20-04/24302

Comment: It says "Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found."  I assume this is a 22.04 vs. 20.04 issue, because while I'm using Xubuntu my understanding is that's just a different set of high-level applications and a desktop that isn't a bloated mock Mac monstrosity.

Answer (score 0):

It was a DHCP problem.  I set up the wireless connections to look to the Google DHCP servers, and my problems seem to have gone away.

[image]